# Old grid-based puzzle game with snakes that wake up when on the same row/column as you

Tags: identify-this-game

I'm trying to find an old game:

- Played on an old computer, not sure which kind. (early/late 1990s?)
- Graphics were grid-based and "8-bit-seeming". Locations included plains and caves.
- Movement was grid-based as well. I think the game was turn-based?
- The main character - which you moved around - might've been a gnome? Maybe not, though.
- One of the enemies which I remember clearly is a snake which usually does not move but "wakes up" when you're on the same row or column as it (unobstructed). It would then move (in a straight line only?) towards you. EDIT: Or actually - it might've killed you instantly in this case?

Edit2: I think you could move between "screens" freely. (Aka either it wasn't level-based, or the levels were larger than a single screen)

That's it for any reliable memories, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 4):

Could it have been one of the [DROD (Deadly Rooms Of Death)](https://drod.fandom.com/wiki/Deadly_Rooms_of_Death) games?

[image]

[image]

> - Played on an old computer, not sure which kind. (early/late 1990s?)

The first game came out in 1996 for Windows 95 and 3.1.

> - Graphics were grid-based and "8-bit-seeming". Locations included plains and caves.
> - Movement was grid-based as well. I think the game was turn-based?
>
> I think you could move between "screens" freely. (Aka either it wasn't level-based, or the levels were larger than a single screen)

Yes to all of those. The graphics were redone a few years later and then looked like [this](https://www.evidentlycube.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/kddl-screenshot-beethro-is-creeped-out-by-eyes.png): still pretty primitive though.

> - The main character - which you moved around - might've been a gnome? Maybe not, though.

Beethro Budkin is human, but he's so ugly that you might mistake him for a gnome. In the redrawn graphics he's even uglier.

> - One of the enemies which I remember clearly is a snake which usually does not move but "wakes up" when you're on the same row or column as it (unobstructed). It would then move (in a straight line only?) towards you.

The [evil eyes](https://drod.fandom.com/wiki/Evil_eye) (shown in the second screenshot) fit your description except that they aren't snakes. There are also [snakes](https://drod.fandom.com/wiki/Snake), but they're always awake.

> EDIT: Or actually - it might've killed you instantly in this case?

There is another monster type ([Aumtlich](https://drod.fandom.com/wiki/Aumtlich)) that paralyzes you in line of sight, which tends to be fatal, but they first appeared in the third game, released in 2007.

Comment: No, though my love for DROD is definitely what resurfaced the memory of this game :)

Comment: @secondperson Oh well.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be [Paganitzu](https://store.steampowered.com/app/358230/Paganitzu/)? It has snakes, caves, turn-based, etc.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vF1JKxiu0XU

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that's it (though the snake mechanic does look somewhat similar). The game I remember had, at or near the start, plains, while Paganitzu seems to be fully set inside caves. (Edited in to question).

Comment: Could've been a cheap knockoff of Paganitzu, though...

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't match all of your points 100%, but could you be thinking of *[Adventures of Lolo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adventures_of_Lolo)* or *Eggerland* which it was based on?

> - Played on an old computer, not sure which kind. (early/late 1990s?)
> - Graphics were grid-based and "8-bit-seeming". Locations included plains and caves.

It's a NES game from 1989. Mostly in a cave-like castle.

> - Movement was grid-based as well. I think the game was turn-based?

Not turn based and movement is free, but objects are originally positioned on a grid.

> - The main character - which you moved around - might've been a gnome? Maybe not, though.

No on this point.

> - One of the enemies which I remember clearly is a snake which usually does not move but "wakes up" when you're on the same row or column as it (unobstructed). It would then move (in a straight line only?) towards you. EDIT: Or actually - it might've killed you instantly in this case?

The version that kills you instantly definitely exists, perhaps the moving one too.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not it either. I've edited the question with one difference my memories have over both Lolo and Paganitzu.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be [Super ZZT](https://www.mobygames.com/game/2596/super-zzt/)?

[image: Screenshot]

> - Played on an old computer, not sure which kind. (early/late 1990s?)

✅ Released in 1992 and can run on almost any DOS PC.

> - Graphics were grid-based and "8-bit-seeming". Locations included plains and caves.

✅ CGA text mode graphics that look very typical of the 8-bit era

> - Movement was grid-based as well. I think the game was turn-based?

✅ Grid-based movement. ❌ Not turn-based but runs on a slow enough clock that it might *feel* turn-based.

> - The main character - which you moved around - might've been a gnome? Maybe not, though.

❌ The main character is a blue/white happyface. You do sometimes play as a dwarf in its spiritual successor, MegaZeux. These games have a distinct DnD vibe, so gnomes wouldn't be unusual.

> - One of the enemies which I remember clearly is a snake which usually does not move but "wakes up" when you're on the same row or column as it (unobstructed). It would then move (in a straight line only?) towards you. EDIT: Or actually - it might've killed you instantly in this case?

✅ There are snakes. Snakes with sensitivity zero only move when they're rank/file aligned with you. They only deal 10 damage, but on some rooms, being dealt *any* damage warps you back to the room entrance. You could be remembering this as "death."

> Edit2: I think you could move between "screens" freely. (Aka either it wasn't level-based, or the levels were larger than a single screen)

✅ Has an interconnected world made of distinct rooms. Progress is based on finding colour-coded keys and doors.

Comment: Thanks, but no - it's not ZZT and it wasn't text based. I'm pretty sure it was much more obscure.